# using a PHP file i am inserting data to wordpress from an unity project, While it works on my local machine, it doesn't once i upload to live server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Using a PHP file I am inserting data to WordPress from a unity project, While it works on my local machine, it doesn't once i upload to live server.

Any Ideas what I am doing wrong?

also the php file is located at the root directory of wordpress in the server /var/www/html/

Thanks
Seb

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
$servername = "localhost";
$username =  "root";
$password = "*****";
$dbName = "*****";

//$servername = "localhost";
//$username =  "root";
//$password = "";
//$dbName = "testdb";

//$userTitle = $_POST["userFullNamePost"];
//$userPoem = $_POST["userPoemPost"];

$userTitle = "katherine";
$userPoem = "mansifeld asdlfkjadf asdfadfkj asfdaklsdjf adfkajdfkladf akldsfj";
$post_name = "wellington";
$post_author = "1";
$post_date = "2018-02-25 08:54:11";
$post_date_gmt = "2018-02-25 08:54:11";
$post_modified = "2018-02-25 08:54:11";
$post_modified_gmt = "2018-02-25 08:54:11";


//Make Connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);
//Check Connection
if(!$conn){
  die("Connection Failed. ". mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_posts (post_author, post_date, post_date_gmt, post_content, post_title, post_name, post_modified, post_modified_gmt)
        VALUES ('". $post_author ."','". $post_date ."','". $post_date_gmt ."','". $userPoem ."','". $userTitle ."','". $post_name ."','". $post_date ."','". $post_date_gmt ."','". $post_modified ."','". $post_modified_gmt ."')";

//$wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO 'wp_posts' ('post_title', 'post_content', 'post_name', 'post_author', 'post_date', 'post_date_gmt', 'post_modified', 'post_modified_gmt')
//VALUES ('$userTitle','$userPoem','$post_name','$post_author','$post_date','$post_date_gmt','$post_modified','$post_modified_gmt')");
//
$result = mysqli_query($conn ,$sql);


if (!result) echo "there was an error";
else echo "everything ok should be";

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Is there any sort of error message?  Is the PHP mysql library installed on your target machine?  Are there PHP error messages in your web-server logs?

Comment: and in the browser it gives me the success message, "everything ok" but the sql table is not populated.

Comment: Hi Kingsley - the last error in the log is the following: [Wed Feb 28 02:01:39.047723 2018] [:error] [pid 6792] [client "ipaddresshere":] PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant result - assumed 'result' in /var/www/html/filename.php on line 43

Comment: You have a typo there: `if (!result)` should be `if (!$result)`.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo however that still doesnt fix the problem

Comment: I use php 5.6 in my local server and in the live server it uses 7.0.24. would that matter?

Comment: Check the output of [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: UPDATE: using the mysql_eror didnt bring any errors, so I tested in a different hosting and it still works fine. so there might be something wrong with the current server, the sql version is : 5.7.21and php is PHP Version => 7.0.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.1. any ideas what the problem can be?